# Is setting/getting sessionStorage variable (client side session storage) affected when user disables cookies?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm working on asp.net mvc core. I want to store some data on client side from mvc view page. I want to append a list of values entered by user to the client side data. At last this data will be stored on hidden text box after some JavaScript processing.

I read that cookies as well as local storage gets disabled when user disables cookies. SO i can't use either of them. The next option I found is windows.sessionStorage

*I have searched a lot but didn't found a perfect answer. From whatever info I have collected, **sessionStorage** is stored on client side like **localStorage**. **I read that the session ID's are stored as cookies. What if the user disables cookies? We will be able to set and get session variables or not??***

Comment: If the customer explicitly doesn't want to store data in the browser, why do you want to ignore that desire? What data is it that you are trying to store? Why can't it be in the HTML instead?

Comment: In Chrome sessionStorage has the same limitations as localStorage as far a security goes,.. So the answer is No.

Comment: But there is another way to store session data, store it server side.  You can do this by using query params, urls etc., or even HTTP request headers.

Comment: The page is like this: Names of the 'States' the user wants and each 'State' will have a separate list of 'Districts'. The state and district names will be entered by user. A table shows the states and districts entered by the user at runtime(Table updated when a state/district is added). HTML will clear the data on page refresh. So I m trying to store the States/Districts in a string separated by ' : ' using sessionStorage. Same will be passed to the server on form submit through hidden text box value.

Comment: The server side calls will be increased if session value stored on server side......

Comment: `The server side calls will be increased if session value stored on server side.`  Why?, just render the page with the user prefs that you said you sent using hidden fields.  No extra server side calls required.

Comment: Hmm........ It seems I'll have to make server calls if want to store data. May be I'll be doing AJAX calls. Thanks!!